# DataMapperException: Unable to open connection to "MySQL, MySQL provider 5.0.8.1"

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, connection-pooling, ibatis

I use ibatis with net and my DB is mysql.

This following error occurs now and then and I was unable to find the cause. Any insights what could be the cause for the errors?

iBatis should handle the opening and closing of DB connections? Then I am not sure how this error could occur.

Is it possible to programmatically close the connections?

### Error

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Too many connections
Stack trace
[MySqlException: Too many connections]
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.OpenPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate411()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection(String connectionString)

[DataMapperException: Unable to open connection to "MySQL, MySQL provider 5.0.8.1".]
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection(String connectionString)
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection()
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.DbCommandDecorator.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.MappedStatements.MappedStatement.RunQueryForObject(RequestScope\ request, ISqlMapSession session, Object parameterObject, Object resultObject)
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.MappedStatements.MappedStatement.ExecuteQueryForObject(ISqlMapSession\ session, Object parameterObject, Object resultObject)
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.MappedStatements.MappedStatement.ExecuteQueryForObject(ISqlMapSession\ session, Object parameterObject)
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapper.QueryForObject(String statementName, Object\ parameterObject)
at Sun.Stream.Persistence.SchoolRepository.GetSchoolDetailsByUrl(String\ SchoolUrl) in F:\SVN\Edu\Persistence\SchoolRepository.cs:line 213
at CustomExtensions.FindSchoolUrl(School& school)
at EduPage.Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o,\ Object t, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,\ EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,\ Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

[HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.]
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,\ Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,\ Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.embedplayer_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Can you directly connect to your mysql server?

Comment: @rMX When there is error, I was not able to connect

Answer (score 0):

just execute this command

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1024;
```